# do single AZ AWS RDS instances self heal?

Tags: amazon-rds, failover

I'm aware of "multi AZ" databases "auto failing over" if one side goes down.  My question is, if you have a single AZ RDS database, and the database box "dies" does AWS automatically spin up a new one for you?  Can you expect corruption in these cases?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=281948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS will restart the database if the host has a problem .

"Automatic Host Replacement
Amazon RDS will automatically replace the compute instance powering your deployment in the event of a hardware failure."

I don't know if AWS can guarantee in case of hardware failure that you have all transactions. At least having automatic backup you have the status less than 5 min before the failure.

See https://aws.amazon.com/rds/details/